# What is the best way to determine the number of business days between two dates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create something that calculates a deadline knowing the beginning date and the number of days needed. For example, I'm starting some projects on the 6th of July and I think it will take me 12 days to complete it so the result of my algorithm would be the 21st of July because I'm off during Saturdays and Sundays.

My problem is I'm also off during some special days like the 14th of July (I live in France and the 14th of July is a day off).

Here is my current script :

```js
function generateEndDate(fromDate,total_days) {
    let startDate = new Date(fromDate);
    let endDate = new Date(fromDate);
    let tmpDate = new Date(fromDate); //a bit redundant I know
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+total_days);
    let daysOff = 0;
    let extraDaysOff = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<=total_days; i++){
        tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + 1)
        if(tmpDate.getDay() === 6 || tmpDate.getDay() === 0 || joursFeriesAnnee.includes(tmpDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10))){
            daysOff++;
        }
    }
    endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + total_days + daysOff)
    if(endDate.getDay() != 6 || endDate.getDay() != 0 || joursFeriesAnnee.includes(endDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10))){
        if(endDate.getDay() === 6){
            extraDaysOff += 2;
        }else if(endDate.getDay() === 0 || joursFeriesAnnee.includes(endDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10))){
            extraDaysOff +=1;
        }
    }
    console.log(daysOff);
    console.log(extraDaysOff);
    console.log(endDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + daysOff + extraDaysOff)
    $(date_fin_input).val(endDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10))
    
}
```

joursFeriesAnnee is an array with every day off for the current year in France,
If the deadline is during a weekend or a day off then I skip to the next Monday / day (I will have a problem with my algorithm if the last day is Friday but it's also in joursFeriesAnnee or if the Monday is in joursFeriesAnnee. But for now I didn't encounter this case.
 Example of i/o:

```
fromDate = 15/06/2020
total days = 23

my output = 19/08/2020
expected output = 17/07/2020 (4 weekends + 14th of July = 9 days off)

and my console.logs outputs:

6
0
2020-08-19
```

How can I approach this?

### Clarification

If I have 1 day needed the deadline should be the same as the starting day 
If the start day is Fri then Fri + 1 is Mon 
If the start day is Thu and Fri is a holiday then Thu + 1 is Mon 
If for a certain period like 250 days the number of weekends + holidays returns something like: startingDay + (weekends + holidays) = Sat, Sun or Holyday then I need to adjust my deadline to the next week or day by adding this weekend or holiday in my count of days off.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want, but I think it would be as follows. Do you want to know what date it will fall in a few days disregarding Saturday and Sunday? For example, today is June 11, 2020, and you want to know how many days of the week you have in 10 days, that is, skipping Saturdays and Sunday, which would be June 25, 2020

Comment: Would it be this?

Comment: Considering besides Saturday and Sunday the vacation days

Comment: Ok, I got it. My question now is in relation to the parameters. Would the first parameter be the date and the second parameter would be the number of days or would it be a second date?

Comment: You need to clarify the rules about adding days regarding whether the start and end days are included in the count. Is Friday + 1 Monday? If so, then is Saturday + 1 also Monday (ignoring public holidays for the moment)?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect because it counts the days off between two dates, then just adds them to the end without considering further days off included in the added days.

If what you're trying to achieve is adding business or working days to a date, consider just looping for the required number of days while ignoring non–working days.

From your comment it seems you want Fri + 1 to be Mon, but also Sat or Sun + 1 to also be Mon so I've modified the code for that so addition is excusive of the start date:

1. Fri + 1 is Mon
2. Fri + 2 is Tue
3. Sat + 1 is Mon

Fri + 0 is  Fri, you should also test the value of *days* and deal with values less than 1.

I've made the test for weekends and holidays a little more efficient and simplified the logic.

```js
/** Add business days to a date
**  Non–working days: Sat and Sun and dates in hols array
**  First work day after start date is included in count, so
**    Fri + 1 => Mon
**    Fri + 2 => Tue
**    Sat + 1 => Mon
**  @param {Date} date - start date
**  @param {number} days - business days to add
**  @returns {Date}
**/
function addBusinessDays(date, days) {
  // Holiday array in YYYY-MM-DD format
  let hols = ['2020-07-14'];
  // Formatter for holiday array format
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-ca',{
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit'
  });
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  let d = new Date(+date);

  // Increment date required number of times
  while (days > 0) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    // Only decrement count if it's not Sat or Sun or holiday
    days -= d.getDay() % 6 != 0 && !hols.includes(f.format(d));
  } 
  
  return d;
}

[[new Date(2020, 6, 2), 1], // Thu 02 Jul 2020 + 1 day  => Fri 03 Jul
 [new Date(2020, 6, 3), 1], // Fri 03 Jul 2020 + 1 day  => Mon 06 Jul
 [new Date(2020, 6, 3), 2], // Fri 03 Jul 2020 + 2 days => Tue 07 Jul
 [new Date(2020, 6, 4), 1], // Sat 04 Jul 2020 + 1 day  => Mon 06 Jul
 [new Date(2020, 6,13), 2], // Mon 13 Jul 2020 + 2 days => Thu 16 Jul (14 Jul is holiday)
 [new Date(2020, 6, 6),12], // Mon 06 Jul 2020 +12 days => Thu 23 Jul (14 Jul is holiday)
].forEach(arr => {
  console.log(`Start: ${arr[0].toDateString()} plus ${arr[1]} = ${addBusinessDays(...arr).toDateString()}`);
});
```

This method is OK for small ranges, but for longer ranges a more complex algorithm might be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did something like this in my first algorithm using modulos to determine the number of vacation days based on the answer of another StackOverflow topic, but finally, it ended as my script above, with your explanation I did understand what might be the problem. Your answer is good but I need to set the end date considering Sat+1 = Mon and Sun +1 = Mon too and also if Fri is a holiday then Thu +1 = Mon, I did some test yesterday but nothing relevant. I'll try to improve your answer because it seems way better than my current script.

Comment: @LightninWolf—I've changed the do..while to just while so it reflects your clarified requirements.